# How to traverse a recursive generator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

So I have this generator which simply gets subsets from a given array.

```
export class GenerateThings {
    static *generateSubsets(elements: any[], offset: number = 0) {
        while (offset < elements.length) {
            const first = elements[offset];
            for (const subset of this.generateSubsets(elements, offset + 1)) {
                subset.push(first);
                yield subset;
            }
        }
        yield [];
    }
}
```

This works in plain javascript (without types, of course) but when I build it on TypeScript like this, it says

> 'generateSubsets' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.

Is there a way to traverse the resulting subset of a set if we use this recursive approach in TypeScript? Thanks.

Comment: You need to specifically define the return type of the function. It can't be determined automatically because it's recursive.

Comment: It's a generator so there's no return type as nothing is returned. It's yielding something but not returning.

Comment: if your function is not returning anything then the correct return type would be void

Comment: Oop! Not return type, but you can still be explicit about types with `Iterator` or `Generator`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-6.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DemiPixel mentioned in the comments above, you can use the `Generator` type as the explicit return type for your function, such as `Generator<any[], void, void>` which means the generator yields an array of `any`, returns nothing, and expects nothing to be passed when `next()` is called.

However, even better in this case would be to take things to the next level and use generics also, in order to avoid the use of the dangerous `any`:

```
export class GenerateThings {
    static *generateSubsets<T>(elements: T[], offset: number = 0): Generator<T[], void, void> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Btw, I don't think your code will work quite correctly as it stands, I suspect when you said `const first = elements[offset];` you meant `let first = elements[offset++];`

Comment: This works! I'll be using generics from now on.
I am not sure why I have changed my code like that where it should have been a `let first = elements[offset++];` if you check the edit logs. Either way, finally my code compiles. Thank you.